# I'm using Cordova (VS TACO) and want to access Node.js OS methods but receive "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, cordova, taco

I generally work in the backend, so am new to Cordova and Node.js.  I thought that Cordova effectively runs off Node, but if this is the case, why doesn't the "require" method work?

- Have I missed a plugin?
- Does the syntax change?
- Something else?

I've used the "Blank App (Apache Cordova)" template within Visual Studio 2015 which runs without a problem and have been happily playing around with it.  Now that I'm trying to utilise an aspect of Node though - specifically the line:

```
var os = require('os')
```

I receive the error "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'require' is undefined".

Any help would be appreciated as I suspect that I'm missing a few basics....

Thanks.

Comment: client-side cordova?

Comment: That’s right Ayush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova scripts used to make a Cordova build etc. use Node.js for package management. The Cordova JavaScript libraries available in your client app (typically a mobile app) do not use Node.js and are not built on top of Node.js.

Comment: Thanks Neil. So how would I run a node.js server within Cordova then?

Comment: Cordova is just a JS library to enable your JS client app to access various feature of your device. The JS provides an interface to "native" code that your HTML/JS/CSS client app can then use. You won't be using a Node.js server in your client app on the device, so you'll want to look for a Cordova plugin that covers whatever you were trying to look up using Node's os module. e.g. For CPU information, one could use possibly use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-cpu. You can start your plugin search here: https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/